# Could you explain outliers filtering?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, outliers

I have a DataFrame that contains a priori outliers values. I would like to remove at least outliers from "Rainfall" variable. I do it as following. It looks to work but i still have outliers in the second figure. **Is it normal ?**

1. Before removing outliers

[image]

2. Removing outliers

```py
rainfall = df["Rainfall"]
q3 = np.quantile(rainfall, 0.75)
q1 = np.quantile(rainfall, 0.25)

iqr = q3 - q1

upper_bound = q1 + 1.5 * iqr
lower_bound = q3 - 1.5 * iqr

rainfall_wo_outliers = df[(rainfall <= lower_bound) | (rainfall >= upper_bound)]["Rainfall"]
```

3. After removing outliers

[image]

Ps: I have scaled the data before with `MinMaxScaler`

Comment: You should ask your question in English ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing, your condition to remove the outliers is inverted, you should use `(rainfall >= lower_bound) & (rainfall <= upper_bound)`

Now back to the fundamental question. **Yes, this is normal**. Outlier removal (with your method at least), relies on the current distribution quartiles to compute the IQR and decide which points to drop.

However, once you drop the data, **the new population has new statistical parameters**, meaning you will eventually get new outliers, relative to the **new Q1, and Q3**.

This is particularly visible for normal or uniform data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def iqr_outliers_removal(s):
    q1, q3 = np.quantile(s, [0.25, 0.75])
    iqr = q3 - q1
    upper_bound = q1 + 1.5 * iqr
    lower_bound = q3 - 1.5 * iqr
    
    return s[(s>=lower_bound) & (s<=upper_bound)]

# generate random data
s = np.random.normal(size=10_000)

# iteratively remove outliers
s2 = s.copy()
n = len(s2)
out = [s2]
for _ in range(100):
    print('.', end='')
    s2 = iqr_outliers_removal(s2)
    out.append(s2)
    
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(list(map(len, out)), marker='.', ls='')
ax.set_ylabel('data size')
ax.set_xlabel('iteration')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

size of the sample for 100 iterations of outliers removal:

[image: iterative outlier removal]

Now, it can happen that you remove outliers and the new population becomes stable. If you use `s = np.random.uniform(size=10_000)` and run the simulation a few times, there is a chance you sometimes get something like:

[image: stable population]

But this is just by chance ;)