# How to delete abnormal values from particular variable(col) from dataFrame when you have data in lacs

Tags: python, graph, jupyter-notebook, outliers, removeall

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(x) + 1)[::365], x[::365])

plt.plot(dates, CentreLiftEffectiveCurrent)

plt.title('CentreLiftEffectiveCurrent')
```

I'm getting 1e^38 abnormal values for my variable CentreLiftEffectiveCurrent. how can i remove them and plot the graph again with the desired values

Comment: What do you mean by "abnormal" values ?

Comment: Guessing "data in lacs" is some sort of Indian way of describing the number of rows. Please use phrases understood elsewhere too.

Answer (score 0):

A usually good way to filter "abnormal" values is to filter the outliers, i.e. values that are outside a range around the median values fo your dataset:

```
rainfall = df["Rainfall"]
q3 = np.quantile(rainfall, 0.75)
q1 = np.quantile(rainfall, 0.25)

iqr = q3 - q1

upper_bound = q1 + 1.5 * iqr
lower_bound = q3 - 1.5 * iqr

rainfall_wo_outliers = df[(rainfall >= lower_bound) | (rainfall <= upper_bound)]["Rainfall"]
```

you can plot a box plot to see these outliers:

```
df.boxplot()
```

[image]

ps: sorry this is q3 and not q2 on the sketch

[you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70849524/14823310) also a discussion about this