# remove outliers from a dataframe by while looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyspark

i've a dataframe and need to extract the outliers from it, then after that recheck the new dataframe again, if i found another outliers, then remove them also and so on...
The problem here is that i can remove the first outlier only and for the other outliers, i can't combine them with the previous outliers in one dataframe to remove them all from the original data.
i think that there's something not correct in my code and it's logic.

**original DataFrame:-**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':
      ['01-01-2022','02-01-2022','03-01-2022','04-01-2022','05-01-2022','06-01-2022','07-01-2022','08-01-2022','09-01-2022','10-01-2022','11-01-2022','12-01-2022','13-01-2022','14-01-2022','15-01-2022','16-01-2022','17-01-2022','18-01-2022','19-01-2022','20-01-2022'],
     'Value':
      [100,50,60,3,85,15,250,97,150,25,49,64,88,35,154,73,67,48,52,90]})
```

[image]

**The expected data to see:-**

for the first looping we should exclude row number 6 (value: 150)

[image]

for the second looping we should exclude rows number 7 (value: 150) and row 13 (value: 154)

[image]

**The final data to see:-**

[image]

**The code that i've used:-**

```
outlier = []
df2 = []
    
while True:
    Q1 = df['Value'].quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = df['Value'].quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    Lower_Limit = Q1 - 1.5 * IQR
    Upper_Limit = Q3 + 1.5 * IQR

    outliers = df['Value'][((df['Value'] < Lower_Limit)|(df['Value'] > Upper_Limit))]
    outlier.append(outliers)
    df = df['Value'][~((df['Value'] < Lower_Limit)|(df['Value'] > Upper_Limit))]
    df2.append(df)
    
    Q1 = pd.DataFrame(df2).quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = pd.DataFrame(df2).quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    Lower_Limit = Q1 - 1.5 * IQR
    Upper_Limit = Q3 + 1.5 * IQR

    outliers = pd.DataFrame(df2)[((pd.DataFrame(df2) < Lower_Limit) | (pd.DataFrame(df2) > Upper_Limit))].dropna()
    outlier.append(outliers)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)[~((pd.DataFrame(df2) < Lower_Limit) |(pd.DataFrame(df2) > Upper_Limit))]
    df2.append(df2)
    break
```

**The final output:-**

```
print('df before Removing Outliers: ' + str(len(df)))
print('df After Removing Outliers: ' + str(len(df2)))
print('Number of outliers: ' + str(len(outlier)))
print('Max outlier value: '+ str(outlier.max()))
print('Min outlier value: '+ str(outlier.min()))

df before Removing Outliers: 20
df After Removing Outliers: 17
Number of outliers: 3
Max outlier value: 250
Min outlier value: 150
```

Comment: Removing outliers iteratively is not really a good practice as removal is really sensitive to the initial data, please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70849524/could-you-explain-outliers-filtering/70851189#70851189), depending on the exact input you can end up with no little removal or complete exhaustion of the data

Answer (score 0):

@mozway is correct. You are not supposed to iterate over a `Pandas` data frame (although some methods exist, they are not meant to be used like you intend to).

I would suggest something different:

```
def drop_outliers(df, column_name, n):
    
#first define a function to filter the dataframe based on a specific condition
        
     df = df[df[column_name] <= n]
     
     return df #output the filtered dataframe
```

Which you can then apply to your dataframe:

```
filtered_df = drop_outliers(df=df, column_name='Value', n = 150)
# modify n according to your condition (i.e., what is the threshold for a value to be considered an outlier
print(len(filtered_df)
```

**EDIT**:

You are **NOT** supposed to use a while loop this way. I would also recommend checking  [how while loops work](https://python.plainenglish.io/what-are-python-while-loops-ea236a6f6ffa) as it seems you are trying to break an infinite loop with no condition.
However, if you really want to use a `while` loop:

```
outliers = []
df2 = df.copy()

while True:
    Q1 = df2['Value'].quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = df2['Value'].quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    Lower_Limit = Q1 - 1.5 * IQR
    Upper_Limit = Q3 + 1.5 * IQR

    new_outliers = df2['Value'][((df2['Value'] < Lower_Limit)|(df2['Value'] > Upper_Limit))]
    outliers.append(new_outliers)
    df2 = df2['Value'][~((df2['Value'] < Lower_Limit)|(df2['Value'] > Upper_Limit))]

    if len(df2) == 0:
        break

df2 = pd.concat(outliers, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your support, i've read the above link and understood it.
but for get high skills in python as i'm a new beginner, could you inform me what's the issue in my code and how to exclude the outliers with the same way that i've wrote above. i just need to practice for such logics

Comment: @MahmoudBadr check my edit. Please do keep in mind that is somewhat of a weird solution.