# Trimming outliers in the pandas dataframe, using logical operators >= and <=

Tags: python, numpy, operators, outliers

I have a dataframe with 50+ (see an example with 2 only)

```
data = {
"Blood": [26, 48, 41, 80, 66, 40, 7, 73, 60, 61, 52, 76, 40, 53, 2, 9, 100, 59, 99, 82, 100, 82, 62, 73],
"Urine": [76, None, 20, 84, 30, 60, 0, 46, 50, 58, None, 66, 40, 22, 66, 18, 0, 60, 1, 78, None, 80, 77, 83]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am trimming outliers in specific columns, using the function

```
def trim_outliers_replace_with_nan(df, cols):
    for col in cols:
        lo = df[col].quantile(0.025)
        hi = df[col].quantile(0.975)
        df[col] = df[col].where((df[col] > lo) & (df[col] < hi), np.nan)  
    
    return df
```

The output is exactly what I need.

When I want to change operators `>` and `<` and use

```
def trim_outliers_replace_with_nan(df, cols):
    for col in cols:
        lo = df[col].quantile(0.025)
        hi = df[col].quantile(0.975)
        df[col] = df[col].where((df[col] >= lo) & (df[col] <= hi), np.nan)  
    
    return df
```

it returns the full dataframe without trimming at all. I suspected that something is with types of columns. One was `int64` instead of `object` and I fixed it for have consistency.
What am I missing?

Comment: It does work, 3/Urine is different

Comment: @mozway, thanks for your response, but I did not get your comment :)

Comment: You said it doesn't change your df, but it does

Comment: The second chunk of code does not trim outliers in 50+ columns, not sure why

Comment: Your example certainly doesn't demonstrate that. Are you sure that there are outliers given your conditions?

Comment: Yes, because the first function remove them. I understand that my example is not very reproducible, but the dataset is too big

Comment: No, I tried running only the second function and it works. Also be aware that the quantiles will change every time the function runs. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70851189/16343464) of mine for more details.